# how to change the color of our pixels using tkinder?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, pixel

i want to control every pixel of my tkinter program but when i search how, i just found out that the only solution is to use 'canvas' and even if it allows us to draw lines, i think i didnt find out how to change for exemple the color of the pixel (x=200, y=478)
and i m also afraid that when i use my code on a really big size of pixels, the program becomes slow with tkinter.. i m still a beginner for those who havent noticed it yet.. so i m curious to know if there is no tool in tinker that actually is used like it takes the x, y of the pixel and the color you wanna apply! i guess it should be possible bcs how either tkinter is supposed to be programmed.. (i m still a beginner ^^) anyways if this tool exists pls tell me about it and if it is supposed to be as slow as canvas i can actually just try a better code..

Comment: You can use an image instead of canvas.  There is module, like `Pillow.ImageDraw`, which can manipulate pixel individually.

Answer (score 0):

> so i m curious to know if there is no tool in tinker that actually is used like it takes the x, y of the pixel and the color you wanna apply!

There is no such tool. Tkinter simply isn't designed to do this. If you need to control individual pixels in a GUI, tkinter is the wrong tool to use.

Comment: I think Pyxel is another GUI module that could do this.